# FFT convolution for log-domain calculations?

Tags: fourier-analysis, logarithms, convolution, fast-fourier-transform

I'm dealing with convolution among some large functions. Say `f1` and `f2`.

The values `f1(i)` and `f2(j)` are so large that I should store them in the log scale. Say the `log` of `f1` and `f2` are `lf1` and `lf2`.

Since every value should be store in the log scale, my task is to compute:

`log( convolution(f1,f2) )`.

For simplicity, assume `length(lf1)==length(lf2)` and computing only for the top `length(lf1)` elements.

Then, without FFT, the task can be done by the log-sum-exp trick: (In Matlab)

```
lf=zeros(length(lf1),1); %result
for i = 1:length(lf1)
    v=zeros(i,1);
    for j = 1:i+1
        v(j)=lf1(i)+lf2(j-i);
    max_v=max(v);
    lf(i)=max_v + log(sum( exp(v-max_v) ) ); %log-sum-exp trick
```

However, for FFT convolution ( something like `ifft(fft(f1).*fft(f2))` ), the log-sum-exp trick seems hard to implement.

Is there any way out? Thanks!